# Can battery damp current

Tags: battery-charging, current-source

Basically, if there is a device using 40A from battery, but the battery is also connected to (being charged) same voltage (12V) charger, would the battery and charger use 20A each? Problem is, that battery charger can only give 33A, so I was wondering maybe this would work because there are two sources in parallel? Battery has 0.06 ohms of internal resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The *short answer* is **Yes**, the battery can provide current on the load, while it has a charger connected to it.
The *long answer* brings some light on the **behavior of the charger-battery-load** assembly, and suggests some **possible safeguards**, depending on the actual behavior of your setup.

Assuming your charger has some voltage and current monitoring that influences the charging process and “knows” the state of charge of the battery , I would say it is most probably safe from the *Charger’s perspective* to use it connected to the battery and performing a charging process, while  you also drain the battery.

Several chargers nowadays are “smart” and use microcontrollers to monitor V & I, and may have a timer to limit the maximum charging time to “protect” the battery from long-term overcharging. These ones may resume charging if the voltage gets too low, but is important to check if you have a rare model that does not resume charging if the battery discharges again.

**So, how is the *probable* charge-discharge behavior?** In case your load needs higher Amperage that the charger is delivering at the moment, based on the equivalent charging resistance as mentioned:

> “It depends on the (effective) internal resistance of the charger.” by @Lorenzo Marcantonio

For instance if the battery discharges from 14.4 V (let’s say) and for every 100 mV of reduction on battery voltage, the charger increases the charging current by 1 A, it means the equivalent internal resistance is 0.1V / 1A = 0.1 Ohm. In this hypothetical and linearized case, the charging current would only reach 33 A when battery voltage is 11.1 V (14.4 - 3.3). Battery at this voltage of 11.1 V would continue to discharge, but at a lower rate of 7 A. To simplify the analysis I did not consider in the calculations the internal resistance of the battery, assuming it as ideal (R_int = 0), but the general (dis)charging behavior is still valid.

Each actual setup of Charger-Battery-Load(s) would behave differently. Furthermore, if the load *can* be smaller than the actual charging current, sometimes the battery *charges*, other times it *discharges*. The charging behavior should be then considered too. Based on this, some **possible safeguards should be checked**; if all of them will be necessary, it varies case by case:

1. **Low-voltage cutoff device** (relay). Depending of battery capacity, the rate of discharge will dictate the temporary lowest safe voltage to be discharged. And an hysteresis is also recommended. Let’s assume if battery gets lower than V_bat = V_off = 11.5V you cutoff the discharge process, disconnecting the load. Then charging resumes and when V_bat = V_on = 12.5 V you reconnect the load line.
2. **Thermal protection on the charger** - in the case it does not have already one incorporated. A simpler thermal cutoff switch can be thermally coupled with the transformer core, but electrically insulated from it. When temperature lowers again, power of the charger is reconnected.
3. **Overcharging / overvoltage cutoff** - for the cases where the *load is variable* and charger sometimes can provide all required power to the load, the final charging voltage may never leave the absorption or bulk phase, leaving the battery “floating” at a higher than recommended voltage. Monitoring the battery voltages in such situations may give an indication if the charger leaves the adsorption voltage (as 14.4 V) and goes down to the floating one (as 13.8 V) - *or not!* In this later case, an *over-voltage relay* could disconnect (or turn-off) the charger, protecting the battery from overcharge. This can be more important to be implemented if this overcharge persists for longer periods as days, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the (effective) internal resistance of the charger. Usually if you place the load on one side of the battery and the charger on the other side the wiring impedance (which become significant at these current levels!) let more current from the battery and less from the charger.

However be careful since the charger may not like the load *unless* it's expecially designed for charging under load (some charger are for offline charge duty only). The current from the load and the voltage variation could confuse the charge algorithm (in extreme cases the charger could potentially be damaged by overload)

Comment: are you saying I should put a resistor on charger output?

Comment: well, the wiring itself is the resistor when you route it appropriately. Even milliohms can affect the current sharing behaviour. However be sure your charger can work reliably when the battery is under load